# UITextView does not display my text

Tags: text, uitextview, text-files

I have a list of images (jpg) that I am displaying in the detailView and each image has a corresponding text file with information about the image. I am trying to use a UITextView to display the contents of the text file, but I have trouble getting it to display anything at all. I have made my text view read-only as I do not want to contents of my .txt files to be editable. 
This is what I have:

```
     NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"%@" ofType:@"txt"];
     if (file){
       NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsofFile:file];
       textView.text = textFromFile;
     }
```

Comment: Maybe too basic... but, did you check the frame of the textView to make sure it has height and width greater than 0?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you probably want to use a label to display small snippets of non-interactive text. Afterwards make sure that you link the UI component you decide on with the File Owner in order to actually connect your variable declaration in the code to the UI component. Let me know how this goes!